# Convolution with shifted arguments

Tags: convolution

> Given two function $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ and denote the convultion of the functions by $h(t)$, that is $$f(t)*g(t)=h(t).$$ What is $f(t-1)*g(t+1)$ in terms of $h(t)$?

Have no idea how to treat this question, everywhere I read, it is said, that this isn't a сonventional way of writing convolution.

The only thing that Im thinking about is, if we denote $T_kf(t)$ as$f(t-k)$ (shifting operator),
we can write:
$$T_1f * T_{-1}g$$

And then what?

Answer (score 1):

Given a function $s\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty s(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau$ exists, note that for any $z\in\mathbb R$ we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty s(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^\infty s(\tau-z)\,\mathrm d\tau
$$
by substitution.

Hence, for the convolution:
\begin{align*}
f(t) * g(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)\,g(t-\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau-z)\,g(t-\tau+z)\,\mathrm d\tau \\
&= f(t-z)*g(t+z).
\end{align*}

For $z=1$ this yields $f(t)*g(t) = f(t-1)*g(t+1)$.

---

I agree that "$f(t) * g(t)$" can be considered a bad notation, since $f(t)$ is just a real number, not a function. Here we used $f(t)$ as a shorthand for the function $t\mapsto f(t)$ and $f(t-z)$ as a shorthand for the function $t\mapsto f(t-z)$.

In the notation you suggested, this result might be written as
$$
f * g = T_z f * T_{-z} g,
$$
where $(T_z s)(t) := s(t-z)$.